# How can I find out the JOBCOUNT value of a periodic background job?

Tags: abap

I have a report which creates a background job. The user can decide if the job should be periodic or not. Now I want to show information about the actual job. So how can I find out the **JOBCOUNT** of the following job (periodic) after the old one was executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess SAP would store that information only if it's needed for internal operations.

I think there's no need, so you won't find that information stored anywhere.

You might do an approximation yourself by searching the currently-scheduled job which has its creation date/time (TBTCO/TBTCS) close to the end of a previous one (TBTCO), with same characteristics (including it(s) step(s) in table TBTCP)... You may get inspired from a few programs prefixed BTCAUX (04, 13).

If you do this piece of code, don't hesitate to post it as a separate answer, that could be very helpful for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BP_JOB_SELECT` FM for that, it mainly resembles SM37 selection parameters.

Set `JOBSELECT_DIALOG` param to `N` to omit GUI screen and fill in job name into `JOBSEL_PARAM_IN-JOBNAME` param, these are the only two mandatory parameters.

The `JOBCOUNT` value resides in `JOBSELECT_JOBLIST` table:

[image]

Comment: You see all Jobs with the same name, but not exactly the next periodic one.